# Mutual followers cypher script - neo4j

Tags: database, neo4j, cypher

I am trying to find mutual followers. People who follow me(ID) and also follows one of my follower(followerID) . The relation is [:FOLLOWS{status:accepted}] .

For example,
MATCH (user:User)-[:FOLLOWS {status: 'accepted'}]->(:User {ID:$ID}) RETURN user

This query gives my followers.

How do i find mutual followers when ID and followerID is given?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query:

```
MATCH (user:User)-[:FOLLOWS {status: 'accepted'}]->(:User {ID:$ID})
WITH collect(user) as followers
UNWIND followers as follower
MATCH (follower)-[:FOLLOWS {status: 'accepted'}]->(node)
WHERE node in followers
RETURN follower
```

Comment: Query makes sense. Somehow its returning a relation with status pending as well.Not sure if its query or db problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the triangles like this. You can get the followers of one of your own followers without specifying the followerID.

```
   MATCH (me:User {ID:$ID})<-[:FOLLOWS {status: 'accepted'}]-(mutualFollower:User),
         (mutualFollower)-[:FOLLOWS {status: 'accepted'}]->(myFollower:User),
         (myFollower)-[:FOLLOWS {status: 'accepted'}]->(me)

   // return the list of your followers, with for each the list of followers that you have in common.    
   RETURN myFollower.ID AS myFollower, 
          COLLECT(DISTINCT mutualFollower.ID) AS mutualFollowers
```

Comment: my follower- [a] mutual followers- [b,b]- this is what I get.
 It returns the same mutual follower twice for some reason